# Are we too tough on firstcommers and drupal starters?

Tags: discussion

beeing in open source software and pro bono support for quite a while myself, I got the feeling, that the mood in this drupal stackexchange feels too tough recently.

It might just be me, but this is one of the few places, where on actually can get support - even thou first questions might be not as refined and usefull as they could be.

I'm not saing we should let everything go, but maybe firstcommers could be given the chance of adjusting their question before downvoting them x times, etc. It's also kind of in the nature of drupal, which pulls you in as "click and install" but offers the full depth of modern software development at the same time.

As I said, it's just a personal feeling. I'd rather try to uplift people starting their winded journey into the depth of drupal then to kick their but from post 1...

Best wishes
Andreas

Comment: Voting on Stack Exchange sites is always on the content, never the person. That’s the thing we need to fix IMO, to get that perception changed, to get that information in front of new users before they’re able to post. Discussions on how to do this have been going on with the company for years and years without resolution. The thing is, Stack Exchange is _supposed_ to be high quality, it’s _supposed_ to have a higher bar to entry than, say, a support forum. How new someone is to the tech is frankly irrelevant - if the question is good quality, and useful, it will survive. If it’s not, this…

Comment: …simply isn’t the place for it I’m afraid